# How I can create config file on casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

How to create config.json file which can be edited when moved to another DSL?

i want to implement my url , username, password to that conf file

Comment: What does *DSL* mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just name it config.js and use:

```
var config = require('./config');
```

In config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    ....
}
```